# Equivalent definitions of the limit of a sequence.

Tags: analysis

Given the statement: For all $ \varepsilon > 0 $ ($ \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q} $), there exists $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $n \geq N$ then terms $x_n$ satisfy $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$, can you deduce the definition of the limit of a sequence? i.e. $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$. (assuming $x$ is the limit.)

I know the definition clearly implies the statement above since the rationals are contained by the reals. The part I am struggling with is proving the implication the other way or finding a counterexample that justifies the fact that the statement does not imply the definition.

Comment: Note that any real number less than $1$ lie in some interval $(1/(n+1), 1/n]$ for some natural number $n$…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the "rational" way.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given.

We know that between any two real numbers (and hence between $0$ and $\varepsilon$ also), there are infinitely many rationals. So let us choose a rational number $\varepsilon^\prime$ such that
$$
\varepsilon > \varepsilon^\prime > 0. 
$$

Then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left\lvert x_n - x \right\rvert < \varepsilon^\prime$ for all $n > N$. This holds because of our hypothesis and our choice of $\varepsilon^\prime$ to be a rational number \ldots.

Then as $\varepsilon^\prime < \varepsilon$, so we can conclude that $\left\lvert x_n - x \right\rvert < \varepsilon$ also for all $n > N$.

Hence $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the "real" way also.

Hope this helps.